# замена одного блока div другим div, при клике (разворот блока / анимация / другие варианты)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Подскажите как реализовать следующую задачу.

На части страницы есть 5 блоков (дивы), которые содержат картинку и подпись.
Надо заменить при клике на другой див (описание, категории и т.п.)

*при клике по блоку надо менять туда и обратно

Comment: это же слайдер ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос из разряда "Догадайся сам". Я понял его в таком ключе:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.box')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.box>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.image {
  background: url(https://www.gmkfreelogos.com/logos/S/img/Smile.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.description {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.show {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quibusdam neque adipisci numquam, inventore eius, accusamus, harum alias iste rem expedita nulla, error optio quos?</div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

**UPD** При открытии одного блока, закрывать другие

```
const boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.box')];
boxes.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    boxes.forEach(el => {
      if (el !== this) el.classList.remove('show');
    });
    this.classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо. Возможно ваше решение еще кому нибудь пригодится - https://codepen.io/GemkinCodePen/pen/erXEQd

Comment: А если при таком же варианте - имеется 5 таких блоков и надо чтобы при открытии (повороте) одного блока все другие открытые закрывались.
Можно ли такое реализовать ?

Comment: @Alexabc-code, можно. Добавил в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду Слайдер, то могу посоветовать очень крутой плагин http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
Если напрягает английский язык, то просто переведите страницу на русский язык с помощью браузера. В Chrome это - клик правой кнопкой мыши и - перевести страницу.